# Prove $A\preceq B\neq \emptyset$ and $C\preceq D$ $\implies$ $A^C\preceq B^D$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Question I am working on:
Let A,B,C,D be sets such that there exists injections $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:C\rightarrow D$.
 Prove whenever $B\neq \emptyset$,  $\exists h:A^C\rightarrow B^D$ such that h is injective. ($A^C$ represents the set of functions from $C\rightarrow D$).
 I have solved similar problems to this before - however I am struggling on how to construct a function with domain D despite not knowing any surjections to D itself. (Note this question is equivalent to the question in the title)

Comment: Hint: It's all about composition.

Comment: The statement you are trying to prove is false.  If $A = B = C = \varnothing$ and $D \ne \varnothing$ then $A^C$ has one element, namely the empty function, but $B^D$ has no elements.  But if you add the hypothesis that $B$ is nonempty then you should be able to prove it.

Comment: @DanVelleman thank you - the next part of the question was to find the case where this does not hold (hence why I specified "in most cases"). I will edit the question to clarify B is nonempty!

Comment: Another possibility is to assume that $C \ne \varnothing$.  Knowing what condition needs to be added should help with the proof.  How can you use the extra information that $B \ne \varnothing$ or that $C \ne \varnothing$?

Comment: @DanVelleman There's no need to assume that $C \ne \emptyset$

Comment: I was suggesting that you could assume either that $B \ne \varnothing$ or that $C \ne \varnothing$.  You don't need to assume both, but either one would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\alpha:A\to B$ and $\beta:C\to D$ be injections. Lets define an injection $\gamma:A^C \to B^D$.

Take a fixed $b_0 \in B\; (B \ne \emptyset)$

For $f \in A^C$, define $\gamma(f):D \to B$ as

$$
\gamma(f)(d) =
\begin{cases}
\alpha(f(\beta^{-1}(d))) & d\in \mathrm{Im}(\beta)\\
b_0 & d \not\in \mathrm{Im}(\beta)
\end{cases}
$$

Can you prove $\gamma$ is well defined and injective?